# Is there normally a lexicalized loss of phonemic /d/ in the coda of "depends"?

Tags: pronunciation, speech, phonemes, fast-speech-rules, consonant-clusters

According to a [blog article](https://clil.files.wordpress.com/2009/02/100misproounced-words.pdf) by Steven Norman under the title “My 100 most mispronounced words in English”, the word *depends* should be /dɪˈpenz/ when “correctly” pronounced.

Notice he provides for no /d/ between the /n/ and the /z/ there in the coda. Is that normal with this consonant cluster, or has the author left it out by accident?

I ask because the Longman Dictionary of Pronunciation disagrees with such info. Their [online version](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/depend) gives the base form of the verb as /dɪˈpend/.  In contrast, the [OED disagrees](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/50238) with **both** of those, giving /dɪˈpɛnd/ as the base form of the verb.

It’s sometimes hard to look up the pronunciations of inflected forms in dictionaries. However, a word that you would imagine would be a perfect rhyme for *depends* is *amends*, which [Longman Online](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/amends) gives as /əˈmendz/ although [the OED gives](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/6311) as /əˈmɛndz/.

[Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/download/pronouncingdicti00unse/pronouncingdicti00unse.pdf) show both versions of *amends*, with /əˈmɛndz/ first and /əˈmɛnz/ second. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amends) similarly shows the /d/ as optional with \ə-ˈmen(d)z\ <sup><sub>(albeit via their idiosyncratic and non-standard in-house notation instead of IPA)</sub></sup>.

Is this all just a typographical error in the blog post’s rendition where he forgot to have a /d/ there, or is his version the standard pronunciation we should expect to hear and strive to emulate?

Comment: I noticed that the article shows pronunciation in British English, not American. I'm basing that on how it shows "answer" is pronounced. I don't know if that matters. Also, I don't know what your question is or I'd answer it.

Comment: Why should Longman Dictionary support  mispronunciations?

Comment: Looks as though that PDF shows the *mispronunciation* of **depends**. When I (a British native speaker) say it, the second **d** is definitely there but may be hard to detect.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, the list is definitely intended to show the correct pronunciations (otherwise there are a **lot** of words that the writer does not know how to pronounce himself). There are several errors in the IPA, though – for one thing, it uses a slanted apostrophe to indicate stress, which is incorrect, but there are also just plain wrong phonetic spellings, like /ˡbʊkeɪs/ for _bookcase_ (should be /ˡbʊkːeɪs/ or /ˡbʊk.keɪs/; what’s written is like _bookies_ with an ‘ay’ diphthong in the second syllable).

Comment: @user067531 Nobody is saying they should. The article linked to gives the ostensibly correct pronunciations of a list of words commonly mispronounced by Spanish speakers. One of those ‘correct’ pronunciations is for the word _depends_, given as /dɪˡpenz/, a form which does not match the pronunciation given by dictionaries such as Longman’s.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet sorry I didn't understand what you are replying "No" to. Do you think the list's pronunciation of **depends** is correct? Or that my pronunciation is incorrect?

Comment: @WeatherVane The list’s pronunciation is not correct, but I very much doubt it’s giving the mispronunciation. Rather, it’s giving the correct pronunciation (or intending to), but with an error. If you look at the rest of the list, there’s some idiosyncratic IPA (as well as the outright errors), but the vast majority of the words match how I pronounce them. The text on the first page in the article also talks about having the list hanging in the classroom as a basis for exercises to help students’ pronunciation – a list of incorrect pronunciations wouldn’t do there.

Comment: @WeatherVane I very much doubt you can pronounce the second /d/ in *depends*, although I’ve little doubt you *think* you’re pronouncing it. This is [the famous *prints–prince, mints–mince, cents–sense* controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Prince%E2%80%93prints_merger), where it’s actually a merger because people *can’t* say it differently but *don’t know* that they they can’t. There’s some psycholinguistics at work there. This same thing also applies to voiced versions like *bands–bans*, and accounts for why *sounds* rhymes with *towns*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You’ve got to expect random errors like that: didn’t you see that that guy’s in Spain? The Spanish are terrible at pronouncing English! :)

Comment: @tchrist _Depends_ is a bit different from _prints/prince_, due to the lack of glottalisation – the glottalisation is what makes it so hard to hear the difference even if it’s there. In both cases, though, it’s pronouncing it _without_ the stop that’s difficult: when the tongue blade leaves the alveolar ridge in preparation for the sibilant, it’s almost impossible to avoid the egressive air flow causing a small release, which is basically an alveolar stop. So _pens_ becomes _[de]pends_, not the other way around.

Comment: @tchrist sorry but you are quite wrong to accuse me of *imagining* that I say "prince" and "prints" differently. And those others which contain a slight "t", as "depends" contains a slight "d".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh that’s interesting, I see what you mean. I wonder how many resort to [pʰɛ̃z] for *pens* to avoid the insertion.

Comment: @tchrist well my diction is pretty good, and I am not among the many you cite. Sorry, but please don't project your generalisations onto me. I don't say "of course I do" but have been assuring myself. in particular I do not say "bans" when I mean "bands".

Comment: @WeatherVane I’m sorry you feel insulted by this logic. I would never insult your ability as a native speaker.

Comment: @tchrist your previous remark said that "proves that **many** people..." but not **everyone**. I know that many people do not pronounce that "t" or "d", and while speaking aloud I can hear there is little difference in some pairs of words, and when talking fast, none, but still I categorically do not say "bans" when I mean "bands" and this case the difference isn't even small, let alone imagined, or *impossible*. In this case and in "prince/prints" the *vowel* emphasis is slightly different too. But anyway, what then **is** the common mistake with "depends"? Is it an *imagined* mistake?

Comment: @tchrist I wasn't considering anything to be a mistake, but the author of that PDF does, stating that "depends" is one of the 100 most mispronounced words, but not *how*. I conclude from your remarks that in your opinion it **can't** be the omission of the second "d", but perhaps it is similar to that cited for "control".

Comment: @WeatherVane Right, I can't figure out what he's thinking the common mispronunciation might be for that word. I sure don't know of any. The exact value of the reduced vowel in the unstressed surely can't matter, for example. As Janus observed, his highly nonstandard ("wrong") use of IPA symbols in the versions he thinks are "right" makes all this even harder to fathom. Speculation here may be a waste of time with no "right" answer possible.

Comment: @tchrist here's another example https://www.uv.es/anglotic/accents_of_english/03/examples_of_australian_english.html

Answer (score 3):

It's not the mispronunciation /dɪˈpendz/ that the author is highlighting, it's the mispronunciation /deˈpenz/ (or /deˈpendz/).

In English, it doesn't really matter whether you pronounce it /nz/ or /ndz/. There are native English speakers who pronounce the ending "nds" both ways, and both pronunciations should be equally well understood by most native English speakers.

What the blog article is talking about is common mispronunciations made by *native Spanish speakers*. The cognate of the word *depends* in Spanish is *depende*, pronounced /deˈpende/ with an /e/ as the first vowel. Using an /e/ rather than an /i/ as the first vowel must be the mispronunciation Steven Norman is complaining about.

Comment: The article may also be talking about how native Spanish speakers often get /s/ and /z/ confused, possibly leading to them devoicing the final /z/.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of a more general merger between /nz/ and /ndz/ found in some speakers. [As Wikipedia explains,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters) this can make *bans* and *pens* sound like *bands* and *pends.* This is usually because the /d/ is elided, though it can also involve an epenthetic /d/ being inserted into /nz/.

Comment: Don't believe what you read in Wikipedia! There is no /ndz/, /nz/ merger! This is just a common garden case of dealveolar elision. It is possible because this word form satisfies strict preconditions involving morpheme boundaries, voicing harmony and so forth. There's nothing lexical about it (to answer that aspect of the the OP's concerns).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. If you have an answer that you think is more complete or accurate, feel free to post one; that would be very helpful to OP, and of course helping the asker is our primary goal here.